# How to crop an image in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to crop the parsed image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725501/how-to-crop-the-parsed-image-in-android)

I have an image in my res/drawable folder and I would like to crop (i.e. slice out some part of the image) the image when loading it into an ImageView. However I am unsure how to do this, any suggestions?

Comment: Linked question answer do not answer how to crop, please read it.

Comment: The best library I found to crop images was [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985041/8383332).

Answer (score 40):

From [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap):
"Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the original bitmap."

Pass it a bitmap, and define the rectangle from which the new bitmap will be created.

```
// Take 10 pixels off the bottom of a Bitmap
Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBmp, 0, 0, originalBmp.getWidth(), originalBmp.getHeight()-10);
```

Comment: For me it only worked if I did `originalBmp.getWidth()-1`. Seems like all of the crop dimensions has to fall completely inside the original otherwise the original is returned.

Comment: this should be accepted, so easy.

Answer (score 13):

The Android Contact manager [EditContactActivity](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/ui/EditContactActivity.java;h=3e248ea93dc8b17a0d66306aaade9ea398c32408;hb=HEAD) uses `Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP")`

This is a sample code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
// this will open all images in the Galery
intent.setDataAndType(photoUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
// this defines the aspect ration
intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectY);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectX);
// this defines the output bitmap size
intent.putExtra("outputX", sizeX);
intent.putExtra("outputY", xizeY);
// true to return a Bitmap, false to directly save the cropped iamge
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
//save output image in uri
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

Comment: If I have an image at SD Card/myimage.jpg, How can I put the URI to CROP intent? ie. I want to crop a region of SD Card/myimage.jpg image.

Comment: #Nguyen, have you what you commented.

Comment: @ rds,
I can crop the image using above code, but the camera crop activity is still running outside my app, how to finish that intent, when user press save or cancel in the crop intent

Comment: Of course it runs outside your app. Read the Intent: 1. It runs in the application that handles `com.android.camera.action.CROP`. 2. The output in saved in the `uri` that you specify. Last thing: Start this activity with `startActivityForResult` to know whether user pressed OK or Cancel.

Comment: This approach means that you have to have permissions to access folders and in kti kat and higher need to add documents permission. If I am not mistaken

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
ImageView ivPeakOver=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewID);

Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImageID);
int width=(int)(bmp.getWidth()*peakPercent/100);
int height=bmp.getHeight();

Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0,0, width, height);
ivPeakOver.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

From the Docs:

```
static Bitmap    createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source bitmap.

Comment: Nice! Still silly it can't be done with a simple attribute on the ImageView though, but I guess this should be efficient enough.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to equally crop the outside of the image, you should check out the ScaleType attribute for an ImageView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

In particular, you would be interested in the "centerCrop" option.  It crops out part of the image that is larger than the defined size.

Here's an example of doing this in the XML layout:

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/title_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:padding="4dip"/>
```

Comment: its so silly they didn't add more crop options then center crop...

Answer (score 4):

```
 int targetWidth = 100;
 int targetHeight = 100;
 RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 100, 100);//was missing before update
 Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
 targetWidth, targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
 Path path = new Path();
 path.addRect(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);
 canvas.clipPath(path);
 canvas.drawBitmap(
 sourceBitmap,
 new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
 new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight),
 null);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(targetBitmap);
```

Comment: You set the path to the rect "rectf", but don't define it. How do you calculate the dimensions of the clipping rect to properly clip the center of the bitmap? I.e. not clip from the corner out.

Comment: The approach to use Bitmap.createBitmap that takes a source image should be a lot more efficient unless you need to modify the bitmap further. Since it creates an immutable bitmap, it does not have to make a copy. (unless the source is mutable)

Comment: what is rectf? please reply

Comment: This code working for scale image not for crop !

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/15/crop-an-image-in-android/