# unable to find com.android.camera.CropImage activity in android

Tags: android

I am trying to run PhotoStream sample from following link

> http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/android-photostream.html

But when i try to set the wallpaper of an image ( reference class ViewPhotoActivity.java) i am getting following error

> ```
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
> ```
>
> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.android.camera/com.android.camera.CropImage};
>   have you declared this activity in
>   your AndroidManifest.xml?

and i think the following code is causing the problem

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(mFile));
intent.putExtra("outputX", width);
intent.putExtra("outputY", height);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", width);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", height);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
intent.putExtra("output", Uri.parse("file:/" + mFile.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE);
```

As i tried to find the solution  of this problem but didn't get any.

Comment: Try changing `intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");` to `intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "CropImage");`

Comment: Nope ! still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way by following the LogCat while i was cropping a contact Image.  It called the Intent with following parameters:

```
cmp=com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.CropImage
```

So try to replace the `com.android.camera` with `com.android.gallery`.  This worked for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setClassName("com.android.gallery", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
```

On some Android version, including the newest, com.android.gallery doesn't exist anymore.
You need to use this then:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gallery3d", "com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage");
```

Answer (score 19):

Actually there are quite a few apps, which offer the CROP action in Android 2.x: the standard Gallery, or Flikie Wallpapers just to name a couple.  Why resolving the intents successfully fails, is that Google changed the components which provide the API. In Android 1.x that might have been com.android.gallery, but since (I think) API9/Android 2.3.x the default gallery is provided by Cooliris, so it is something like com.cooliris.gallery, etc.

The correct way to resolve the intent on any phone is (code, which I use):

```
// this is something to keep our information
class CropOption
{
    CharSequence TITLE;
    Drawable ICON;
    Intent CROP_APP;
}

// we will present the available selection in a list dialog, so we need an adapter
class CropOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CropOption>
{
    private List<CropOption> _items;
    private Context _ctx;

    CropOptionAdapter(Context ctx, List<CropOption> items)
    {
        super(ctx, R.layout.crop_option, items);
        _items = items;
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        if ( convertView == null )
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from( _ctx ).inflate( R.layout.crop_option, null );

        CropOption item = _items.get( position );
        if ( item != null )
        {
            ( ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.crop_icon ) ).setImageDrawable( item.ICON );
            ( ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.crop_name ) ).setText( item.TITLE );
            return convertView;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The layout for the item should be a horizontal linear layout with an IconView and a TextView.  I will skip it for brevity's sake, by now you most probably know how to do it :-)

Now for the part where we find the intents and present them for selection (this is only the relevant part of the function, onActivityResult):

```
try
{
    final List<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    // this 2 lines are all you need to find the intent!!!
    Intent intent = new Intent( "com.android.camera.action.CROP" );
    intent.setType( "image/*" );

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
    if ( list.size() == 0 )
    {
        // I tend to put any kind of text to be presented to the user as a resource for easier translation (if it ever comes to that...)
        Toast.makeText( this, getText( R.string.error_crop_option ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
        // this is the URI returned from the camera, it could be a file or a content URI, the crop app will take any
        _captureUri = null; // leave the picture there
        break; // leave this switch case...
    }

    intent.setData( _captureUri );
    intent.putExtra( "outputX", 128 );
    intent.putExtra( "outputY", 128 );
    intent.putExtra( "aspectX", 1 );
    intent.putExtra( "aspectY", 1 );
    intent.putExtra( "scale", true );
    //intent.putExtra( "", true ); // I seem to have lost the option to have the crop app auto rotate the image, any takers?
    intent.putExtra( "return-data", true );

    for ( ResolveInfo res : list )
    {
        final CropOption co = new CropOption();
        co.TITLE = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel( res.activityInfo.applicationInfo );
        co.ICON = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon( res.activityInfo.applicationInfo );
        co.CROP_APP = new Intent( intent );
        co.CROP_APP.setComponent( new ComponentName( res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name ) );
        cropOptions.add( co );
    }

    // set up the chooser dialog
    CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter( this, cropOptions );
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    builder.setTitle( R.string.choose_crop_title );
    builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item )
        {
            startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get( item ).CROP_APP, ACTIVITY_CROP );
        }
    } );
    builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog )
        {
            // we don't want to keep the capture around if we cancel the crop because we don't want it anymore
            if ( _captureUri != null )
            {
                getContentResolver().delete( _captureUri, null, null );
                _captureUri = null;
            }
        }
    } );
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    Log.e( TAG, "processing capture", e );
}
```

And there you have it... Hope that helps, I lost 2 days trying to figure it out...

Comment: This won't work any more because some developers change the underlying android classes so "com.android.camera.action.CROP" doesn't always exist.

Best making your own.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to let the application save the picture first and manually crop it, i.e.:

```
                    Intent intentPick = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                intentPick.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");//TODO fails in Android 2.x

                List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intentPick, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                if (list.size() > 0)
                {
                    intentPick.setData(selectedImageCropped);
                    intentPick.putExtra("outputX", 240);
                    intentPick.putExtra("outputY", 240);
                    intentPick.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                    intentPick.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                    intentPick.putExtra("scale", true);
                    intentPick.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                    intentPick.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedImageCropped);
                    startActivityForResult(intentPick, PROCESS_IMAGE);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.w(Tag, "PHOTO CROPPING IS INDEED NOT SUPPORTED.");

                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), FROM_IMAGE_SELECT);
                    Toast.makeText(ContactAdder.this, R.string.select_image_from_sdcard_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

A success result leads to:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case FROM_IMAGE_SELECT:
                selectedImageCropped = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TEMP_IMAGE_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                /** Crop selected image. */
                final Intent intentSelect = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                intentSelect.setData(data.getData());
                intentSelect.putExtra("outputX", 240);
                intentSelect.putExtra("outputY", 240);
                intentSelect.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intentSelect.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intentSelect.putExtra("scale", true);
                intentSelect.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                intentSelect.putExtra("output", selectedImageCropped);
                startActivityForResult(intentSelect, PROCESS_IMAGE);
            break;
```

And then process your cropped image.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle the `CropImage` activity with your app package so it is independent on Android version.

Here's the project:
https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

> The CropImage activity extracted from Gallery.apk (AOSP 4.4.4).
>   Compatible with Android API Level 15 and up.

Remember to add the following line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<!-- Declare the bundled CropImage Activity -->
<activity android:name="com.android.camera.CropImage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading that this was an undocumented feature and doesn't exist in any API. It is now [not accessible in 2.x](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/2dd647523926192c/4b6d087073a39607?tvc=1&pli=1future)

> If there is
>   no constant in the SDK for the string 
>   "com.android.camera.action.CROP" then
>   this is simply not a part of the SDK, 
>   and has a chance of breaking in the
>   future

Comment: so what is the ultimate solution ?

Comment: There appear to be some options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android Not tried any of them myself...

Comment: None of one is helpful sorry !!

Comment: I am trying to crop an image in android 2.3.3. None of these is helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove:

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
```

it will ask from which application you want to crop image.