# App Crash in Crop Activity in 2.1,2.2 etc but works in 1.6

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-2.1-eclair

Hi Friends,

I want to use the Crop Activity but it will Crash as

to activity {com.CropActivity/com.CropActivity.CropActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:

Its Code is Properly Working in Andorid 1.6 but its Crash in 2.1 or 2.2. 
please give me solution 
Thanks in advance

This is my Code for Start the Crop Activity.

```
 Intent i = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
           i.setClassName("com.android.camera","com.android.camera.CropImage");
           i.setData(data.getData());

            image.setImageURI(data.getData());


            Log.d("Camera", "path: " + data.getData().getPath());
            i.putExtra("noFaceDetection", false);
            i.putExtra("outputX", iconWidth);
            i.putExtra("outputY", iconHeight);
            i.putExtra("aspectX", iconWidth);
            i.putExtra("aspectY", iconHeight);
            i.putExtra("scale", true);

            i.putExtra("output", Uri.parse(iconUri));

             i.putExtra("return-data", true);
             startActivityForResult(i, CROP_IMAGE);
```

Comment: what is `com.CropActivity.CropActivity` and have you declared it in your manifest?

Comment: Yes the com.CropActivity.CropActivity is just my File name..

Comment: in your intent your trying to call the android crop image activity. That's not part of the API so the string names are different. See my post for possible solutions/alternatives. You should not use that activity for your application as it is different on different phones.

Comment: @HardikGajjar : at which line it crash ? put error log and also the code of startActivityForResult(...)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the CropActivity that exists on android by default then it is [not officially part of the API](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/2dd647523926192c/4b6d087073a39607?tvc=1&pli=1) so the intent string has probably changed.

See these links for possible solutions/alternatives

- [unable to find com.android.camera.CropImage activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904685/unable-to-find-com-android-camera-cropimage-activity-in-android)
- [How to crop an image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android)