# Crop a drawable image by android gallery cropping method

Tags: android, imageview, crop

Onclick of my Imageview,I want to crop the background image of the imageview  which is in drawable folder of my app by default cropping technique of android gallery and the cropped image should set in same  once it is cropped.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.croppingactivity/drawable/apple"), "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("crop", true);
    //intent.putExtra("output", Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.croppingactivity/drawable/apple"));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

and this is my stacktrace.

```
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT dat=android.resource://com.example.croppingactivity2130837504 typ=image/* (has extras) }
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at com.example.croppingactivity.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-04 10:21:28.812: E/AndroidRuntime(2553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but it doesn't work.I am getting activity not found Exception.
What I am doing wrong please help me.

Comment: http://kyogs.blogspot.in/2012/08/image-split-and-merge.html refer this one.hop its helpful to u

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But I dont want to crop in that way.I want to crop like how android gallery does.

Comment: maybe your device is missing the application which does the crop function.

Comment: @AndroSelva I am using Galaxy nexus device android gallery works with that .

Comment: Look this question for help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904685/unable-to-find-com-android-camera-cropimage-activity-in-android

Comment: @faylon bad luck, it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the code I'm using to do such thing. Maybe you can try it :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");

intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
// Scale the image down to 400 x 400
intent.putExtra("scale", true);

intent.putExtra("windowTitle", "My_title");
    // You need to use a temporary file for cropping to work
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("crop", "png",
              myActivity.getCacheDir());
mSavedUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
intent.putExtra("output", mSavedUri);
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "PNG");

profileActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_PICK_PICTURE);
```

I guess you'll have to change `intent.setType(...)` to `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://..."), "image/*")`

Comment: Hum, that's weird. Is your `onClick()` method inside your Activity's class ? I'd like to know if you invoke `startActivityForResult` on the current activity instance, or on another objet...

Comment: sorry for the late reply.onClick is inside my activity and invoking startActivityForResult in the same activity

Comment: That's really strange. Are you absolutly positive that the ActivityNotFoundException occurs on the startActivityForResult ? Can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply again i posted my stacktrace along with my question.pls check.Thanks