# How to make a shape dragable and re-sizable in android dynamically

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas, draggable, resize-image

I am a newbie in android and i am making a simple app in which i select an image from the gallery, a rectangle is drawn on the image which the user can drag at any position on the image and re-size the rectangle dynamically.

My code up-till now can load an image from the gallery and draw a rectangle on the image. But i don't know how to go about making the rectangle dragable dynamically.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity   {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        bMap = bMap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);

        float width = imageView.getWidth();
        float height = imageView.getHeight();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bMap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);  
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(width/2+60, height/2-20, width/2-60, height/2+20, paint);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);

    }


}
```

}

[image: Output]

The output i want is something like in the above picture. The red rectangle can be resized and dragged by the user and then save the image.

Comment: So the purpose is to crop the image?

Comment: No the purpose is just to highlight a particular portion...

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom view that represents the rectangle you drew. In the `onDraw(...)` you can set the `Paint` of the rectangle and it's initial size. Now the concept is, that when it is touched on it's corners and dragged, the x and y coordinates of the rectangle will change when the user lifts their finger(s) from the screen. I will refer you to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) on the Android Developer Guide on how to create a custom view. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188478/how-to-make-view-resizable-on-touch-event) is a similar question post on here that may give you some ideas.

Comment: How is the touch event done.. i understand that ill need to create a custom view.. but the dragging is linked to the view.

Comment: @Vikram The touch events are done in the `onTouchEvent(...)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: How to set the new view.. i.e is the rectangle view in the above code.. i.e i made a new view and the ondraw() method and also the touchevents. how can i link it to the above code... i.e what to do when the imageview loads..

Comment: You can create the new view programmatically over the image with an initial x and y coordinate, and then the user will resize and drag it.

Comment: Can you please tell me or give me a link of how to add my custom view over the image view dynamically.. i am having a lot of trouble doing it.. thanks