# Get New Points from Angle Android

Tags: android, math, geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

I am trying to make a Re-sizable touch view which I made successfully. You can find code [How to make view resizable on touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188478/how-to-make-view-resizable-on-touch-event/16359447#16359447).

It has 4 corners. You can re-size that rectangle by dragging one of corner. But now I want to enhance that logic and want to put rotation in that code. I successfully find angle when user touch center of one of the edge of rectangle. But now problem is I can't get new position of corners so that I can redraw that rectangle and rotation is possible.

Question is : **How can I calculate 4 corners new position based on Angle?**.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the angle by which to rotate then you don't need to calculate the rectangle's vertices. 
A simple way to do it would be as below

```
@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(60.0f);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100, paint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
```

Comment: I know that scenario to rotate canvas.. but then after points were on their old place. Next time I can't find new place of 4 corner points on canvas. This will not work my friend.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to calculate new coordinates based on a rotation angle... It's probably simpler than you think:

```
x' = x × (cosα - sinα)
y' = y × sinα × cosα
```

So, you just apply this programmatically, considering where `x'` is the rotation result of `x` and the same for `y'` and `y`, and `α` is the rotation angle.

`cosα` and `sinα` functions are available in Java as `Math.cos(α)` and `Math.sin(α)`, but attention: in Java, all trigonometric functions uses radians and not degrees as angle, so you can consider this:
`rad = deg * 180 / π`
Applicable as:

```
double deg = 45d; //Put instead your degrees
double rad = deg / 180 * Math.PI; //The radians convertion
```