# Change Size of Canvas Rectangle in Android with Multitouch

Tags: android, canvas, multi-touch, drawrectangle

Can anybody Post an Code Example how to change size of a Canvas Rectangle by Using Multitouch in Android?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188478/how-to-make-view-resizable-on-touch-event

Comment: I'm able to Draw a Rectangle with Touch and I'm able to move the Rectangle. My Question is, how to change size  of Rectangle with Multi Touch. I can't see any solution in this Example for Multitouch.