# How to use part of a image in canvas

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, png

I need to use a part of a image in my canvas. Is there any function to crop a part of a png in android?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one [How to crop an image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android)