# Get image within the camera overlay

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, surfaceview, camera-overlay

[image]

I have a camera overlay(Imageview) on my custom camera currently. I have got everything working. Now just need to get the image within the overlay. How do I go about doing this. Did a lot of research but didn't find an efficient way to do it.

P.S. If you are giving me negative points please also state the reason.

```
    private Camera.PictureCallback mJPEGPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        CameraConfigurationUtils.releaseCamera();
        ProcessImageAsyncTask processImageAsyncTask = new ProcessImageAsyncTask(CameraActivity.this);
        processImageAsyncTask.setTaskCompletedListener(new ProcessImageAsyncTask.OnImageProcessingCompletedInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onImageProcessComplete(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                enablePreviewMode();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, transparentView.getHeight(), transparentView.getLeft(), transparentView.getWidth(), transparentView.getHeight());
                cameraPreviewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                File pictureFile = CameraImageUtils.getOutputMediaFile();
                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();


 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture size in " + ((float) (pictureFile.length()) / (1024 * 1024)) + " mb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            processImageAsyncTask.execute(data);
        }
    };
```

Comment: please show me some relevant code

Comment: did you try something so far? how relevant is that overlay? (thinking in a good UI/UX).

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: it is about taking picture where is your overlay image ?

Comment: if you are adding your overlay image in xml , then why not set image in xml ?

Comment: The screenshot shows an overlay on camera live preview. After I take a picture I need to get the image only within the overlay

Comment: so you want the image only set in the overlay image not outside the overlay image

Comment: Exactly. Basically I want to crop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android

Comment: I have tried this but I get out of memory exception

Comment: I guess you are merging these two images , I think the above given link is good , i would suggest you two ways , first following the upper given link is good , but if it is giving you exception then it clearly means that you need to scale down your camera image before doing any work on it

Comment: 2ndly , before drawing camera preivew why not set the camera preview size according to the overlay imageview so that it just looks like that, and let the other part clip itself of preview

Comment: Thank you. I will try these

Comment: Efficient: send camera preview to SurfaceTexture. Render the desired portion on an offscreen pbuffer with OpenGL ES. Retrieve RGB pixels with `glReadPixels()`. See https://github.com/google/grafika

Comment: Would this be possible for API 10 ?