# cut the portion of bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to crop the parsed image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725501/how-to-crop-the-parsed-image-in-android)

I have selected a portion from the bitmap and i am copying the selected portion in the same bitmap.. Now i want to remove the selected portion after copying.. How to do it?? please help me out..

Comment: @Bill-the-Lizard: This is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Easiest way I am aware of is to use XFer mode processing from the Graphics package. Function below cuts region starting from (30,30) till (100,100) to the 320x480 image loaded from resources. Adapt coordinates to change dynamically:

```
private Bitmap cropBitmap1() {
    Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.image1); 
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null); 
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 100, 100, paint);

    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: hey this will clear the entire bitmap.. i want to clear only the selected portion after copying.

Comment: not entire, just portion. Try and you will see. I checked the code before posting.

Comment: hai here in the   p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));            it shows An error that  Assign Statement to a new local variable (CLEAR) what is this

Comment: Looks like you forgot: import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: But i want to find distance dynamically. how can i do that? please help me

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. What distance you want to find?

Comment: This one saves the day. This is more useful then Bitmap.createBitmap as we can clean/remove any shape pixels from the bitmap and not just adding padding to bitmap.

Answer (score 156):

Just in case someone is trying to solve same problem, there is a better solution: [`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). For example, if you need to crop 10 pixels from each side of a bitmap then use this:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 10, 10, originalBitmap.getWidth() - 20, originalBitmap.getHeight() - 20);
```

Comment: How can I extract a rectangle from a dynamic bitmap (a bitmap captured from the camera) ?

Comment: Didn't get your question. The same approach would work - cropping the bitmap is the same as extracting rectangle from it

Comment: @a.ch. i want to cut the some top side area on image with bitmap...
any solution regarding this?

Comment: use the same approach - cut any number of pixels from top

Comment: Is there something like that for copying from one bitmap to another, as opposed to allocating a new bitmap?