# how can we convert FaceDetector.Face to bitmap image in android?

Tags: android, image

in my application i have 2 images(ex:2 persons photos),

one background image is there
one foreground image is there.
                  now i want to cut face part from foreground image and attach that face to background image and finally i want to generate final image contain background image body and foreground image face.

Could you please  help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> how can we convert FaceDetector.Face to bitmap image in android

The algorithm will be sort of like this :

- Get the [mid points](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html#getMidPoint%28android.graphics.PointF%29) of all the [faces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#findFaces%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.media.FaceDetector.Face%5B%5D%29) in the Image, whose [confidence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html#confidence%28%29) is > 0.4
- Roughly calculate a rect around the face which is about the dimensions shown in the image; the distance between the eyes is `A` . If you can get an oval shape proportional to the eye distance, it is even better.
- [Crop the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432495/cut-the-portion-of-bitmap/5432782#5432782) from the coordinates you've just calculated

<sub>............................</sub>[image: cute isn't she :D]

Note: you have to take care of the [Euler angles too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), if the face is tilted.

Comment: thank u for your reply.but problem here is the return type of getMidPoint() is PointF .Here is the code.                           PointF eyesMP = new PointF();
    getFace.getMidPoint(eyesMP);
    eyesDistance[i] = getFace.eyesDistance();
    eyesMidPts[i] = eyesMP;

Comment: thank you for your reply.could you please tell how to draw rectangle.i am trying to draw rectangle but it is asking left,right,top,bottom but not width and height..

Comment: now how can i replace background image face with foreground image and how can we generate final image(ie background image face and foreground image face)