# Select part of bitmap and save it

Tags: android, bitmap

I have bitmap `Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);`

I want to select specific part of bitmap (with specific x,y,width,height) and save it as new bitmap.

I tried this but doesnt work (only cropped it)

```
  public Bitmap getSelectedImage(Bitmap paImage,int,x,int y,int paWidth,int paHeight){

     Bitmap newPicture=Bitmap.createBitmap(paImage,x,y,paWidth,paHeight);
     return newPicture;
     }
```

Like in this picture[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cut the portion of bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432495/cut-the-portion-of-bitmap)

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code.  You are returning the copied section, not cropping the original.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using this method but you can simply make new bitmap and use two for loops to copy every relevant pixle to new bitmap. Currently I'm not at computer but if u want I can send you code tomorrow. However this is not very fast, but also not much slower then  built in methods like the one you are using.