# Crop image and watermark it

Tags: java, android, image, watermark

I need to apply a watermark to a picture after it's been cropped, but something has gone wrong. My app takes a picture from the camera, launches a try to crop it and then applies a watermark.
This is how I save the picture after having taken it from the camera (not cropped.)

```
Uri uriSavedImage = null;
if (front) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    directory_path = date.toString();
    directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), directory_path);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/"+ directory_path + "/front.jpg"));
    OutputStream imageFileOS;

    try {
        imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(    uriSavedImage);

        imageFileOS.write(current_pics);

        imageFileOS.flush();

        imageFileOS.close();
        runCropImage(uriSavedImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the attempt to crop the image:

```
private void runCropImage(Uri pic_uri) {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(pic_uri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 4800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 4800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (data != null) {
            String cropImagePath = null;
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            cropImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/" + directory_path + "/front.jpg";
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(cropImagePath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                watermark(Uri.fromFile(new File(cropImagePath)), bitmap);
            }

        } else {
            // TODO do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I apply the watermark:

```
public void watermark(Uri pic_uri, Bitmap bitmap) {

    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pic_uri.getPath());

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(1200, 1200, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.watermark);

    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, canvas.getWidth() - waterMark.getWidth(),
            canvas.getHeight() - waterMark.getHeight(), null);

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(pic_uri.getPath());
        result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the watermark is applyed correctly, however the picture gets scaled!
So I have inside a new image, the cropped picture at the beginning of the picture (top left) and a watermark at the correct position (bottom left,) however the rest of picture is black.
**So what's wrong?**
The source cropped image has the correct dimension, 1200x1200 (verified by using a file manager), and the watermarked picture does too.

I've also tried to verify the dimension on "bitmap" object inside watermark function, but I got 300x300.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe the crop is defective. Here is the code I used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725501/how-to-crop-the-parsed-image-in-android

Comment: I need that user choose position of crop. The strange thing is that saved image has correct size, but relative Bitmap inside my code has a different size

Comment: It is something do with density. Try to use setDensity with DENSITY_NONE. Link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setDensity%28int%29