# How to resize image without loosing image content

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to resize an image to a smaller image like thumbnail. I have used following options

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 200, 700, false);
```

and

```
ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail()
```

Both of these options cut parts of images. So they don't look good. I just want to reduce image dimensions and don't want to loose image content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize a bitmap eficiently and with out losing quality in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327846/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-eficiently-and-with-out-losing-quality-in-android)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627727/cropping-image-by-setting-height-dynamically/47627812#47627812

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrease image size without losing its quality in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424942/decrease-image-size-without-losing-its-quality-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

you have to try like this

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth)
{
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath,bmOptions);

   //Part 1 :withcompression Sacle image 200 pixels x 700 pixels this size you can customize as per your requirement

   Bitmap withCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,200,700,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize an image without losing quality and images are from drawable/mipmap then you should try pngquant.

https://pngquant.org/

Comment: He want to do programatically